# App is force closed

Tags: android

I am creating an app which requires a custom layout.But after running my app it simple force closes.Can anyone suggest the reason and solution if possible

Thanx in advance

this is my main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }  
}
```

this is my custom layout class

```
public class Odo extends View {
    private Paint p;
    private RectF rect;
    public Odo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.e("odo", "constructor");
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void init() {
        Log.e("odo", "inside init()");
        rect = new RectF();
        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        Log.e("odo", "inside onSizeChange");
        rect.set(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("odo", "inside onDraw");
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(rect, p);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.e("odo", "inside onMeasure");
    }
}
```

And this is my XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.example.odo.Odo
        android:id="@+id/odom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is look at the logcat.  This will usually tell you exactly which line is causing the problem.

Comment: this is the logcat returns        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.odo/com.example.odo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.example.odo.Odo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to provide the default constructors that takes `AttributeSet` and/or `int` for style reference. For example:

```
public class Odo extends View {
    private Paint p;
    private RectF rect;

    public Odo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.e("odo", "constructor");
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Odo (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.e("odo", "constructor");
        init();
    }

    public Odo (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Log.e("odo", "constructor");
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Log.e("odo", "inside init()");
        rect = new RectF();
        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    }

//.....  and so on

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your custom view you need to override the constructor that takes an `AttributeSet` parameter in order to use it in an XML layout:

Just replace

```
public Odo(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.e("odo", "constructor");
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

by

```
public Odo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.e("odo", "constructor");
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```